# How to trigger an ALEXA notification programmatically?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alex

I searched extensively but cannot find any example code that would allow me to understand how to trigger the Alexa notification that makes the orange light come up?

I believe it has to do with the SetDirective (function?) ... I just don't get it.

Here's what I like to do, I'd really appreciate some guidance or hints.

1. Create an Alexa skill that triggers the orange light based on a condition.
2. speaks content when Alexa is asked

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: there isn't any way through which alexa can respond automatically. You always have to invocate it.

Comment: How? That's my question. i cannot find any documentation that would explain that in more detail

Comment: It's not supported yet. Notifications for alexa is coming soon. https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/8cc45487-d5fb-413b-b6c7-eeea4794d10c/amazon-announces-notifications-for-alexa-feature-is-coming-soon-sign-up-to-stay-tuned

Comment: https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/5bef2f03-a3ff-4042-b8ec-a1e9196169a2/the-alexa-voice-service-makes-new-notifications-feature-available-to-device-makers

It is available now,

Comment: @N.K That's for the Alexa Voice Service, i.e. devs integrating Alexa in to their own hardware, it still isn't available for the Alexa Skill's Kit :(

Answer (score 1):

https://ifttt.com/connect/amazon_alexa/if_notifications
You can setup notifications and the user can ask if they have any notifications, because alexa will be blinking and showing that there is a notification waiting.
"Alexa do I have any notifications?"

Comment: OMG, why do I have to beg Alexa to tell me if someone is breaking into my house?! Using Stringify I can get my Nest cameras turn on my lights when someone is breaking into my house and IFTTT will then trigger a Notify Me skill then sends me a useful "Someone is in the Driveway" audible notification. Alexa then very helpfully doesn't bother actually making the announcement until I ask it three days later when I notice the annoying green ring, completely pointless..........

Comment: we also dont get the full developer kit that like uber gets and the major companies.. we get a slim downed version

Answer (score -1):

You can actually do this with the NotifyMyEcho skill.
Here's an example with cURL.

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"notification": "string","accessCode": "ACCESS_CODE","title": "string"}' 'https://api.notifymyecho.com/v1/NotifyMe'
```

You can find more info about it [here](https://www.thomptronics.com/about/notify-me).

Here's the link to the [skill](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BB2FYFS) as well.